# Drag events to another month while using left/right keys - have working except current calendar droppable area is previous area

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using [Full Calendar v5](https://fullcalendar.io/). I have `editable: true` which allows events to be dragged around the calendar.

**Issue**

There does not appear to be a means of dragging events to different months than the current month ([various GitHub requests](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2542)).

**My Workaround**

I therefore looked into creating a quick workaround by making the left/right keys on the keyboard navigate the months on dayGridMonth while dragging.

**My JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        editable: true,
        events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?overload-day'
    });

    calendar.render();
    
    jQuery("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
            calendar.prev();
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
            calendar.next();
        }
    });
    
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.0/main.min.js'></script>

<div id="calendar" style="width:700px; height: 700px;"></div>
```

**Works except**

- Mouse down on the "All Day Event" on the 1st October (to drag)
- While dragging press left on your keyboard
- Still while dragging the event hover over the last 2 rows in the September view
- You will notice that it's remembering the cell sizes of the view you dragged from (November)

**Fix?**

Is it possible to stop this happening or is it simply not possible due to the way the current month is remembered during the drag event which cannot be updated as the months change while dragging?